# python does not find wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

In order to start building a gui I've decided to install wxPython, however I can't get it working. I run python 2.7.6 (in IDLE it shows: Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:24) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32) and it works fine.

When I however try to install a 32 bit or 64 bit version of wxPython from http://www.wxpython.org/download.php it doesn't work, meaning that when I run:

```
import wx
```

I get the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\****\Desktop\Python GUI test\test1.py", line 2, in <module>
import wx
ImportError: No module named wx
```

I think it might go wrong with the place where it installs wxPython. Normally however it uses the right directory automatically. It tries to install in the following dir:

```
C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\Lib\site-packages
```

Which is in a program called Canopy which I once installed but don't know how to get rid off. I've installed it in this dir and I've also installed it within the dir where Python is installed:

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages
```

Both of these locations don't work.

Anyone has an idea where things go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to clean up your installations.  Canopy is part of Enthought, so if you don't need this anymore de-install it, I would think you can do that from: Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features

Then re/install the Python version you want to use, would suggest 2.7.8 32 bit and then install wxPython 3.0.1 32 bit for Python 2.7.

To test it do not use "Idle" as it is written in Tkinter, which will cause conflicts with wxPython.  Just test it with

```
c:\Python27\python.exe
import wx
```